# How do I avoid the query calling associated objects

Tags: java, hibernate

I am sure there is a hibernate term for this but I am not sure what it is (and I could therefore probably look up the answer) but here goes.

I have a Product Pojo where one of the fields is a Set of Suppliers (also a Pojo). When I call to get a list of Products, by default it queries to get the list of Suppliers- which is what I would expect.

However, sometimes I do not require the data in the Set and the querying it is taking too long to just bear it. Is there a way to sometimes avoid querying the data for the Set?

Or is my design incorrect?

My Product.hbm.xml mapping file has:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping SYSTEM "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping default-access="field" default-lazy="false" package="model">
<class name="model.Product" table="PRODUCT">
    <id column="PRODUCT_ID" name="id" type="long">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    ...

    <set name="suppliers" sort="unsorted" table="SUPPLIERS">
        <key column="PRODUCT_ID" />
    <one-to-many class="model.Suppliers" />
    </set>

    ...

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: can you update your question with hibernate mapping files or with entity classes if you are using annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of Hibernate is what you are expecting: All collections mapped for an entity, and all associated entities, be it through `to-many` or `to-one` associations, are not loaded by default.

But if you have defined the `lazy="false"` for the `Set of Suppliers`, Hibernate will fetch the associated collection eagerly along with the `Product`.

Change the `suppliers` mapping as below, so that Hibernate will not fetch it eagerly:

```
<set name="suppliers" sort="unsorted" table="SUPPLIERS" lazy="true">
        <key column="PRODUCT_ID" />
    <one-to-many class="model.Suppliers" />
</set>
```

**EDIT:**

The above mapping is the default fetching strategy for `suppliers`. Now if you want to load `suppliers` along with the `Product`, you can override this default strategy at runtime in code:

```
String productSelect = "select p from Product "
                + "p left join fetch p.suppliers "
                + "where p.productName=:pname";
Query query = session.createQuery(productSelect);
query.setParameter("pname", productname);
Product result = (Product) query.uniqueResult();
```

The above query will fetch the `Product` along with the set of `suppliers`. So, wherever needed, you can override the default strategy by using above query to get `suppliers` along with `Product`.

Comment: Better still remove this default-lazy="false" and override as required at either the mapping level, or in individual queries.

Comment: I now have "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: model.Suppliers, no session or session was closed". Would it not query to get the data when required?

Answer (score 0):

Set the fetchtype to LAZY (instead of EAGER) for the supplier Set.